# How to have frame of reference of an object to be at it's tip than its center (Unity3d)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, rendering

I have got an imported .obj object (mesh) which I am trying to render in Unity. The  default frame origin for this body is at the center of the object:
[image]

Currently, all the transforms are performed with this frame (so if I change the position coordinates the center of the shaft is what is moved). How do I change this frame to be fixed to one end of the shaft? (so that when I give positions of the tip, the tip is moved, and the rest of the shaft follows accordingly?)

TL:DR - How to shift the body frame to its tip when the default is its centre?

Comment: Make it a child of an object, and place the parent on the tip. Then manipulate the parent position etc. It's called usually called "anchor".

Comment: Or re-export from your 3D studio of choice after moving it off the origin.